# Would disabling hyperthreading improve the performance of polars?

Tags: python, python-polars

Cloud providers such as [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/wellarchitected/latest/high-performance-computing-lens/compute.html) recommend disabling hyperthreading for HPC applications.

As someone who is only vaguely familiar with what that means, I am left wondering: Would disabling hyperthreading on my machine have any potential to improve the performance of polars (and, for that matter, other parallelized python libraries for data scientists)?

Comment: Why not just go and try it? It's pretty easy to revert the change in the BIOS.

Comment: The logic is that hyper threading lets you do more work on a physical core when it's not saturated with computational work. Since a high performance numerical library *should* be saturated the cores, there shouldn't be an advantage to hyper threading. But you'd have to test to be sure.